# Getting None type for object when running method outside of __init__

Tags: python, class, methods, init

For the following class

```
class Member(object):
    def __init__(self, fields, scouts, id):
        self.id = id
        self.fields = fields
        self.scouts = scouts
        self.routes = [Route(s) for s in self.scouts ]
        self.routeBreak = []
        self.numScouts = len(self.scouts)
```

I run this method

```
def createMember(self):    
    random.shuffle(self.fields)
    self.routeBreak = self.createBreaks(len(self.fields))
    self.assignRoutes()
```

Example:

```
Member.createMember()
```

However, after doing so, the object Member comes back as "None".  I tried adding createMember() to the **init** method

```
class Member(object):
    def __init__(self, fields, scouts, id):
        self.id = id
        self.fields = fields
        self.scouts = scouts
        self.routes = [Route(s) for s in self.scouts ]
        self.routeBreak = []
        self.numScouts = len(self.scouts)
        random.shuffle(self.fields)
        self.routeBreak = self.createBreaks(len(self.fields))
        self.assignRoutes()
```

And then everything is fine.  I can run my other methods on the object no problem.  I have no idea why this is happening and I need to figure out how to run createMember() outside of the **init** method.  I am fairly new to using Classes and Methods so any explanation would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do `m = Member(); m.createMember()`?

Comment: I tried that, as well as `Member().createMember()` (which I wasn't sure if that was even legal).

Comment: I just realized I forgot to add the arguments when creating `m = Member()`.  Thanks for making me take a second look at that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Tim's question, when using classes, you have the class definition, a type, and then an instance of the class, the object.

createMember should be called as a method of *an instance*, not of the class itself (there is a type for that - a staticmethod or classmethod, and they do not have a "self").

So you need to create the instance:

```
m = Member()
```

Note - you will need the parameters to do that. If you want it to not need the parameters, that requires a bit more code.
Then access that method in it:

```
m.createMember()
```

You could also call it inside _init__ (known as the constructor), where "self" is the instance:

```
self.createMember()
```

Comment: Ah!  I realize my mistake.  When doing `m = Member()` , I forgot to add the arguments for the init function, and when I tried just adding `createMember()` to the __init__ I remembered the arguments.  Your answer cleared up some confusion I had about creating the class vs creating an instance, though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As `createMember` needs an argument `self` which should be the instance itself, you can't call it by `Member.createMember()` because this makes it a unbound method without Member instance as the required argument. Member is a class not an instance. You have to call it by `Member.createMember(memberInstance)` to explicitly provide the instance itself.

`Member().createMember()` doesn't need to give the argument is because `Member()` has created an instance which will implicitly serves as the first argument `self`.